# Correct application of Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: statistics

I am struggling with the following question:

A random variable $X$ takes only values in the range $[0;12]$.
Mean and standard deviation are $10$ and $0.45$ respectively.
Give an upper approximation for $P(X\leq7)$.
For what do you need the condition that $X$ has values only in $[0;12]$.

I think the estimation can be done using Chebyshev's inequality $P(|X-\mu| \ge c) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{c^2} $

$X\leq7$ means $X$ must be between 0 and 7 considering that it must be in the interval $[0;12]$.

So I set $\mu = 3.5$ and use

$P(|X-\mu|\leq3.5) = 1-P(|X-\mu|\ge3.5) \leq \frac{0.45^2}{3.5^2}$

and  get $P(X\leq7) \ge 0.9835$.

What is wrong with my approach?

Thank you for any hint and comment.

Comment: Hint: $\mu$ is a specific number and is not free to be chosen.

Comment: Does $[0;12]$ mean integers or real values in that interval?  In particular is $X=10.0675$ possible?

Comment: Why do you say $\mu =3.5$ rather than $c=10-7=3$? Why are you using a two sided version of Chebyshev's inequality when the question is one sided?  Your answer is clearly much too big so you may have a sign error too

Comment: @Henry Unfortunately it is not specified, but I assume its Integer

Comment: I Ah I see, the one sided version make a lot of sense to me. Still don't know how to deal with the fact that the probability below 0 is 0. Thanks so far!